# Single RadioButton Select in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, radio-button

In a gridview how can I do single radiobutton select without using JavaScript

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="GroupName" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField
```

Answer (score 1):

Give Different name to each radio button control and remove groupname attribute

e.g.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2"  runat="server"  />
```